# How can i modify certain android kernel to recognize external wifi adapters?

Tags: android-wifi, usb-otg, android-kernel

When i flashed my custom rom i tried to see what it recognizes because the stock kernel was not recognizing this atheros external adapter which was connected with OTG cable. So when i typed in the terminal (in this case i was using Termux, which is a whole linux environment) `lsusb` and it recognized the atheros bus but when i tried to install the drivers nothing has worked how it is supposed to do.

Note: I am posting the question here bacause if i was about to drop it in the android section i might be linked to post it in the unix but then the question body contains programming parts in it and becase of that i've posted it here.

Comment: Actually, SO runs on code, so my guess is that your question won't have much success here. Maybe it will if you improve your question so to include more details about the *programming*  side your mentioned.

Comment: Okay i will try to be more detailed!